# Are the values of partial differentials of higher order for this function the same?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The given function is $f(x,y) =  \lvert x^2 - y^2 \rvert$

The question is to verify that $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$ at $(0,0)$

The solution has one part that I'm unable to comprehend

It starts with

$$ f_{xy}(0,0) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f_y(h,0) - f_y(0,0)}{h}$$

Where we have

$$ f_y(0,0) = \lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{f(0,k) - f(0,0)}{k} = \lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{\lvert k^2 \rvert}{k} = 0$$

And
$$ f_y(h,0) = \lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{f(h,k) - f(h,0)}{k} $$

$$ = \lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{\lvert h^2 - k^2 \rvert - \lvert h^2 \rvert}{k} $$

Here they have provided the condition that if $ h^2 > k^2 $

Then

$$ = \lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{(h^2 - k^2) - h^2}{k} = 0$$

And proceeded further.

My doubt is precisely in this step. How can they just take only the value of $ h^2 > k^2$ and move on? What about if $ k^2 > h^2$? If the latter is true  then won't this imply that the partial differential $f_{xy}(0,0)$ doesn't exist?

They have also similarly assumed if $h^2 < k^2$ to prove existence of $f_{yx}(0,0)$.

According to my understanding the values of the variables of $h,k$ (taken for the limits) vary independently of each other. So why have they taken these assumptions?

Comment: For a fixed $h^2>0$, the limit $k\to 0$ means that there is a point where $k$ will be less than $h$

Comment: Oh ok, so $h$ will remain a constant when $k$ is tending and vice versa. Thanks, I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as Andrei mentioned in the comment , while one of the values of $h$ or $k$ is tending the other non-tending value however small it may be, will always end up greater than the tending value, as the tending value tends to zero.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).